# Python - differentiating similar images

Tags: python, image, opencv, comparison, detection

I am trying to detect the differences in two images in python (object present or not). I tried different approaches with opencv and pillow for python. The goal is to check if an object is present or not. And if possible i want to extract the coordinates of the changes (with a bounding box)

The problem is, that the images are not 100% identical. There is always a very slight change in angle or lighting. Thresholding didnt do the trick as expected....

Is there any other approaches that you would suggest?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Objects like you could identify with YOLO?

Comment: Post example images to some free hosting service and put the URLs in a comment. Also post your code for what you have tried.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the **Structural similarity index** for a robust image comparison:

https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/transform/plot_ssim.html

This is implemented on **scikit-image** package.